# Where's the SDK for Windows 8 Developer Preview

Tags: windows-8

So I've downloaded and installed the Windows 8 Developer Preview with developer tools, but I can't find the SDK.

The download page says that it contains the Windows SDK for Metro style apps, but I can't find it. Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jay says, the SDK headers and tools are located in \Program Files(x86)\Windows Kit.  The [samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/) and [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/) are online.

Update: The whole pack of samples can had as a single download [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Developer-Preview-6b53adbb).

Comment: I guess that explains why I couldn't find the samples, do you know if there is some way we can download all the samples at once. It's a bit painful having to download them individually.

Comment: Just found it, all the samples are contained in a zip file located at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Developer-Preview-6b53adbb, which was first link in the URL above.

Answer (score 1):

It is located in `<System Drive>\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kit`

Are you having any specific problems that is resulting in Windows SDK not being found?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the documentation? If you install the x64 version with developer tools (4.8GB) it has visual studio and expression blend 5 installed which lets you develop Metro UI apps.